# table not being appended to the content

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, ejs

I have a button which when clicked, pops up a model that asks for number of rows and columns, and then adds the table with those specs to my editable div beside it. The table should be appended to the end of contents of the div. How do I do it?

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="information" class="col col-lg-10">
            <div id="heading" contenteditable="true"></div>
            <div id="content" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-2">
            <button id="table-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Table</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Table specs</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <form action="/" method="post">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="rows">Rows &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</label>
                                    <input id="rows" name="rows" type="number" min="1" step="1" placeholder="&nbsp;amount" value="5" required>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="columns">Columns&nbsp;:</label>
                                    <input id="columns" name="columns" type="number" min="1" step="1" placeholder="&nbsp;amount" value="5" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <span class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</span>
                                <button id="add-table" class="btn btn-primary">Add table</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="backend.js"></script>

</body>
```

The code pen link(It also has JS) : https://codepen.io/vighnesh153/pen/xyQreo

Github link(to avoid dependency issues): https://github.com/vighnesh153/Debugging/tree/master/Editor

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code can generate an table based on the rows and columns enter by the user.
Add the div element( `<div id="tableDiv"></div>`) into the html where you want to insert your table.

```
var addTableBtn = document.querySelector('#add-table');

addTableBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var rows = parseInt(document.body.querySelector('#rows').value);
  var columns = parseInt(document.body.querySelector('#columns').value);
  generateTable(rows,columns);
});

function generateTable(rows,columns){
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  for(var r = 0 ; r< rows ; r++){
    var row = table.insertRow(r);
    for(var c = 0; c< columns; c++){
      row.insertCell(c).innerHTML = "Column_" + c;
    }
  }

  document.body.querySelector("#tableDiv").appendChild(table);
}
```